# List of distributions with closed-form Laplace transform?

Tags: probability, distributions, references, moment-generating-function

Is there a compendium of distributions (my main interest are those with support on ${\mathbb R}_+$) with a closed form Laplace transform?

I am only aware of the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Laplace_transform) as an instance where the Laplace transform is available in closed-form, but I wonder if there are other obvious cases. I think another example is the generalised hyperbolic distribution.

Comment: Many continuous distributions have a closed-form Laplace transform (uniform and normal distribution as well). For probability distributions, the transform is often called "Laplace-Stieltjes transform". Perhaps it is easier to find a table if you search on that term.

Comment: If you look at the distributions on wikipedia, up to a change of sign of the argument, the MGF is a Laplace transform; if there's a closed form MGF there'll be a closed form Laplace transform. You can find lists of mgfs in many texts, but usually for a smaller set of distributions